# Правильно ли говорить: "Блистай во всём цвете!"

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Блистай во всём цвете!

Правильно ли так говорить?

Comment: Желательно указать контекст, если вы хотите  получить корректный ответ. Такой краткой фразы недостаточно, а додумывать текст тоже большого смысла не имеет. Лишняя трата времени и негарантированный результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Желательно распространить выражение, например: ***Блистай во всем цвете молодости и красоты.***

Из Нацкорпуса: во всем цвете молодости, силы, мужества, красоты и т.д.

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2%EE+%E2%F1%E5%EC+%F6%E2%E5%F2%E5+

Answer (score 0):

Грамматических ошибок нет, а что автор конкретно имеет в виду – то неведомо.

Comment: Я не про правописание спрашиваю. "Блистай во всём цвете" - так допустимо говорить? Правильно ли ?

Comment: Да здесь не очень понятно, что автор имеет в виду, поэтому и о "правильности" говорить трудно.

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксически правильно, а стилистически плохо.

Минимальное изменение:

**Блистай во всём своем цвете!**

Из Нацкорпуса:

> Но прежде, нежели я стану говорить об Альамбре, мне хочется привесть один из лучших мавританских романсов, в котором описан наружный вид ее в то время, когда мавританская Гранада была еще **во всем своем цвете**. [В. П. Боткин. Письма об Испании (1847)]